# Sed: adding a substring in the middle of a variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to change the directory of all C headers like `#include "library.h"` to `#include "prefix/library.h"` in a file using the sed command, but I can't figure out how to add a prefix to the middle of a string. So far I've tried this command:

```
sed -i "s"\/'#include[[:space:]]*[<"][^>"]*[>"]'\/"$prefix"\/ $filename
```

but it replaces the whole string instead of creating `#include "prefix/library.h"`. Is there any way to change it while keeping the original `#include, <, "` and spacing?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post more clear samples of your Input  and expected output in your post inside CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: It's not clear what output you desire. You seem to be looking for `sed` backreferences; briefly, `&` lets you recall the entire matched string, and `\1`, `\2` etc backslash-parenthesized subexpressions from the match. You also seem to need a thorough refresher on the shell's quoting facilities.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear, I'm trying to for example change #include <header.h> to #include <prefix/header.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this:

```
sed "s%#include[[:space:]]*[<\"]%&$prefix/%" $filename
```

explanation:

- You can use any separator with `sed`, I use `%` as a separator, to avoid trouble with `/` inside your filename
- `&` means: the whole matched regex. To this way the pattern you just matched is printed again.
- this command searches for `#include "` and adds the `$prefix` just after that match.

Comment: Thank you, & to match the regex was what I was looking for :)

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to SO. If an answer solves your question, please accept it (you'll get 2 reputation points). If any answer was helpful, you can upvote it (once you have enough reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^"]*\)\(\"\)\(.*\)/\1\2prefix\/\3/'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
#include "prefix/library.h"
```

---

---

In case you have a shell variable then try following.

```
prefix="prefix"
sed "s/\([^\"]*\)\(\"\)\(.*\)/\1\2$prefix\/\3/" Input_file
```

Where your Input_file is as follows:

```
cat Input_file
#include "library.h"
```